# MapView show completly after screen turned on again

Tags: android, android-maps-v2

i've this problem with MapView inside my layout:

once added it shows buttons, google logo, the grid but no map. To make it visible i've to turn the screen off and then on. What's the problem?

Here my code

```
    mapView = (MapView) geo.findViewById(R.id.map_view);
    mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mapView.getMapAsync(this);
    final LocationManager lm = (LocationManager)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    lastKnownLocation = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    if(lastKnownLocation == null) {
        askLocationRefreshInitMapView(lm);
    } else {
        if((System.currentTimeMillis() - lastKnownLocation.getTime()) > THIRTY_MINUTES) {
            askLocationRefreshInitMapView(lm);
        } else {
            initMapView(lastKnownLocation);
        }
    }



private void initMapView(final Location location) {
    lastKnownLocation = location;
    // Gets to GoogleMap from the MapView and does initialization stuff
    mapView.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {

        @Override
        public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
            map.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(false);
            map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

            // Needs to call MapsInitializer before doing any CameraUpdateFactory calls
            try {
                MapsInitializer.initialize(getActivity());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            // Updates the location and zoom of the MapView
            if(location != null) {
                CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()), 10);
                map.moveCamera(cameraUpdate);
                map.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);
            }
            map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(0, 0)).title("Marker"));
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved initializing the map during onCreateView and then adding it on UserInteraction requests

Answer (score 0):

Implement 'OnMapReadyCallback' to your activity or what ever you're using 
then in your onMapready method

```
@Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        MapsInitializer.initialize(context);
        gMap=googleMap;
     if (mapView != null) {
                // Initialise the MapView
                mapView.onCreate(null);
                // Set the map ready callback to receive the GoogleMap object
                mapView.getMapAsync(this);
            }
    }
```

Comment: I did it but put onMapReady on my fragment and implementing it as suggested doesn't show nothing. At least before it was showing a grid. So i tried to put mapView.onResume(); as last instrunction of onMapReady method and now the map displays... but it very weird and i can't figure out why...

Comment: I tried to insert the map inside the fragment layout xml instead of inflate it dinamically and it works. So the problem seems related to inflating a new layout at runtime and attach it to fragment layout. Someone can help me get working on dinamically inflated aproach?

Comment: @tassadar SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.where_are_they_map);
            mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

Comment: use this in your layout xml file <fragment
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:id="@+id/where_are_they_map"
       />  make sure you have given internet access permissions and your class implements onMapReadyCallbacks